# Поиск дубликатов слова по маске

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Как при помощи регулярного выражения найти повторяющиеся слова в пределах одного предложения, либо предложение, имеющее повторяющиеся слова? Одна строка может содержать несколько предложений.

Попытки реализации:

```
select *
from   text_exp
where  regexp_like(text, '(.+)([^.!?])\1\2\1')
```

Этот вариант ближе:

```
select distinct x.*, 
       regexp_substr(lower(text), '(\w+?)\s+(\S*\s)*?\1', level) sub, level
from   ezhus.text_exp x
connect by regexp_substr(lower(text), '(\w+?)\s+(\S*\s)*?\1', level) is not null
AND    PRIOR TEXT = TEXT 
AND    PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL
```

Однако он захватывает еще лишние варианты, такие как края слов, например:

лав`а день ночь а`стра

Частично проблема решена. Следующий запрос выдает предложения, в которых слова повторяются более 2х раз, за исключением предложений, в которых слова идут друг за другом:

```
select distinct x.*,
       regexp_substr(lower(text), '[^[:alpha:]]([a-zа-я]+)[, :;]+.*\1[, :;]+.*\1[, :;]*.*', level) sub,
       level
from   ezhus.text_exp x
connect by regexp_substr(lower(text), '[^[:alpha:]]([a-zа-я]+)[, :;]+\1[, :;]+\1[, :;]*', level) is not null
AND    PRIOR TEXT = TEXT
AND    PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Вы бы все таки ставили на вопрос тег какая у вас СУБД. Я так подозреваю, что Oracle, потому как вы обычно по нему спрашиваете ... Для postgres можно было бы и регулярку придумать, теоретически. У Oracle регулярки слишком слабые - не выйдет. Только бить строки на предложения connect by, потом другим connect by бить на слова и потом уже от этого считать количества. В общем я бы рекомендовал не решать это средствами СУБД, гвозди микроскопом забивать не удобно. СУБД не предназначены для обработки текста

Comment: @Mike мне сказали, эту задачу можно решить одной регуляркой, но как и какой - не говорят

Comment: Одной регуляркой - легко. Если эта регулярка PCRE. А оракл поддерживает только POSIX регулярки. А в них нет заглядывания вперед. т.е. когда вы одно слово захватите и дойдете до конца предложения разыскивая его, назад, что бы проверить следующее слово вы уже не вернетесь

Comment: @Mike А что, если сделать такой connect by, для которого повторяющееся слово будет разделителем? Либо хотя бы найти такую маску, которая будет выделять предложения с повторяющимися словами, без использования PCRE это возможно?

Comment: На первый взгляд без PL\SQL тут никак

Comment: Возможно, я неправильно выразился. Нужно найти ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ, имеющее повторяющиеся слова, сами слова не так важны, важно, чтобы они встречались в пределах одного предложения хотя бы 2 раза

Comment: @daydark Я бы сказал, что это кардинально другая задача. И она "почти" решается обычной регуляркой. Только возникают проблемы что бы понять именно отдельные слова. Нужно утверждение нулевой ширины обозначающей границу слова, `\b` в оракле не работает :(  без него \w+ может хватать любой кусок слова. Требовать же наличие пробелов перед и после слова явно не правильно. там может быть знак препинания например

Comment: А может границей слова быть что-то вроде '[^, .()\|/?!]' ?

Comment: @daydark Я бы с радостью так сделал. только вот точка нужна что бы понять конец предложения и если она будет захвачена при проверке слова то конец предложения будет потерян. Опять упираемся в отсутствие незахватывающих проверок

Comment: Что то ваш новый вариант совсем не решает проблему. Вы же вроде просили что бы искало именно в предложении. А ваш текущий вариант ищет и за его пределами т.е. по всей строке

Comment: @Mike Этот вариант вроде как не выводит предложения, в которых нет повторяющихся слов

Comment: Не предложения, а строки. Строку `text abc. text ` он поймает, потому как на точки внимания не обращает. А именно проверка на точки одна из основных проблем мешающих простому решению

Comment: Если слово встречается хотя бы 3 раза, то выдает. Строку 'text abc. text text' он игнорирует. text abc. text тоже игнорирует)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение двумя регулярками. Вторая учитывает тот случай, когда повторяющееся слово стоит первым предложении. Данное решение выводит колличество предложений, в которых содержится 3 и более повторяющихся слов:

```
select x.*,
       regexp_count(lower(text),
                    '[^[:alpha:]]([a-zа-я]+)[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1')cnt,
       regexp_count(lower(text),
                    '^([a-zа-я]+)[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1[^[:alpha:]]')cnt1
from ezhus.text_exp x
where regexp_count(lower(text),
                    '[^[:alpha:]]([a-zа-я]+)[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1') >= 1
   OR regexp_count(lower(text),
                    '^([a-zа-я]+)[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1[^[:alpha:]]') >= 1
```

Еще один вариант:

```
select x.*
from ezhus.text_exp x
where regexp_like(regexp_replace(lower(text),
                    '^([0-9a-zа-я]+)[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1', ' '||text),
                    '[^[0-9a-zа-я]]*([0-9a-zа-я]+)[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1[, :;]+[^!.?]*\1')
```

Просто выводит строки, где слово в предложении всречается более 2х раз

Comment: Вся загвоздка была в том, что Oracle воспринимает \w как любое сочетание букв, а отдельные слова обозначаются как [a-zа-я]+

Comment: Реагирует на строку `text abc text AtextA` т.е. не проверяет, что повторы - это отдельные слова, а не их части

Comment: Теперь маска должна работать правильно

Comment: Там еще в первой регулярке в конце НЕ альфу добавить и все ok. Я боялся он в этом случае конец предложения потеряет ... Но он не теряет, все верно

Answer (score 8):

Регулярные выражения в оракле слишком слабы, что бы одним выражением получить искомое. Ваш вариант можно допилить до частично рабочего результата - он максимум сможет находить одну пару слов, а если между ними были при этом другие слова - то их не найдет. Это возможно только с помощью забегающих вперед проверок, которых в POSIX регулярных выражениях, используемых Oracle, нет.

Единственный путь который я вижу: сначала разбить текст на предложения. Затем, каждое предложение разбить на слова и дальше с этими словами работать обычными средствами SQL, т.е. группировкой и подсчетом количества.

```
with TEXTs(TEXT) as(
 select 'text abc gef text nm. text this is test abc this abc.' from DUAL
  union all
 select 'this is row two of the test text, word "text" is double.' from DUAL
)


select ID, pnum, word, p
  from (
    select ID, p, pnum, regexp_substr(p, '\w+', 1, level) word
      from (
        select ID, regexp_substr(text, '.*?(\.|$)', 1, level) p, level as pnum
          from (select lower(text) as text, rownum as ID from TEXTs) x
       connect by regexp_substr(text, '.*?(\.|$)', 1, level) is not null
              and PRIOR ID=ID and prior dbms_random.value is not null
      )
      connect by PRIOR ID=ID and PRIOR pnum=pnum and prior dbms_random.value is not null
             and regexp_substr(p, '\w+', 1, level) is not null
  )
  group by ID, p, pnum, word
 having count(1)>1
```

Результат:

```
ID  PNUM    WORD    P
 1     1    text    text abc gef text nm.
 1     2    abc     text this is test abc this abc.
 1     2    this    text this is test abc this abc.
 2     1    is      this is row two of the test text, word "text" is double.
 2     1    text    this is row two of the test text, word "text" is double.
```

Comment: Кстати, как работает prior dbms_random.value is not null в данном случае? Он же никогда не выдает значение null

Comment: @d А он и не должен. Оракл прервет запрос с ошибкой "Цикл в данных пользователя" в том случае, если все указанные в connect prior значения ранее уже встречались и как только мы пишем проверку prior id=id то попадаем на такую ошибку потому как одно и то же встречается много раз. рандом же не повторяется (теоретически)

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример своего кода, который вполне себе работает, учитывая то обстоятельство, что нужно найти три и более повторяющиеся слова в одном предложении.

```
select * from(
select id, regexp_replace(Z_3, '^', ' ')||' .' as Z_4 from(
select id, regexp_replace(Z_2, '\s+','  ') as Z_3 from(
select id, regexp_replace(Z, '[?!.\]',' .') as Z_2 from (select x.*,
  regexp_replace(slova, '[—\,;:]','') as Z
from text x)y)))
where regexp_like(Z_4,
                '(\s([а-я|\-]+)\s)([^\.]*)\1([^\.]*)\1([^\.]*)\.', 'i');
```

Идея заключается в том, что я убираю из основного текста разделители, оставляя только точки, каждое слово предложение ограничиваю двумя пробелами и переделываю многострочный текст в одну строку.

Comment: Пробел с точкой добавлен для того, чтобы учесть то обстоятельство, что если вдруг в таблице присутствует текст без точки в конце вовсе. Вот.

Comment: ИИС Консалтинг?